# Merging queries of same table N times

Tags: c#, sql, linq, group-by

I have a table of word, a lookup table of where those words are found in documents, and the number of times that word appears in that document. So there might be a record that says Alpha exists 5 times in document X, while Beta exists 3 times in document X, and another for Beta existing twice in document Y.

The user can enter a number of words to search, so "quick brown fox" is three queries, but "quick brown fox jumped" is four queries. While I can get a scored result set of each word in turn, what I actually want is to add the number of occurrences together for each word, such that the top result is the highest occurrence count for all words.

A document might have hundreds of "quick" and "brown" occurrences but no "fox" occurrences. The results should still be included as it could score higher than a document with only one each of "quick", "brown", and "fox".

The problem I can't work out is how to amalgamate the 1 to N queries *with the occurences summed*. I *think* I need to use GROUP BY and SUM() but not certain. Linq preferred but SQL would be ok. MS SQL 2016.

I want to pass the results on to a page indexer so a for-each over the results wouldn't work, plus we're talking 80,000 word records, 3 million document-word records, and 100,000 document records.

```
// TextIndexDocument:
// Id | WordId | Occurences | DocumentId | (more)
//
// TextIndexWord:
// Id | Word

foreach (string word in words)
{
    string lword = word.ToLowerInvariant();
    var results = from docTable in db.TextIndexDocuments
                  join wordTable in db.TextIndexWords on docTable.WordId equals wordTable.Id
                  where wordTable.Word == lword
                  orderby docTable.Occurences descending
                  select docTable;
    // (incomplete)
}
```

**More information**

I understand that full text searching is recommended. The problem then is how to rank the results from a half dozen unrelated tables (searching in forum posts, articles, products...) into one unified result set - let's say record Id, record type (article/product/forum), and score. The top result might be a forum post while the next best hits are a couple of articles, then a product, then another forum post and so on. The TextIndexDocument table already has this information across all the relevant tables.

Comment: You are describing a full text index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that you can create a navigation property `TextIndexDocuments` in `Document`:

```
public virtual ICollection<TextIndexDocuments> TextIndexDocuments{ get; set; }
```

and a navigation property in `TextIndexDocument`:

```
public virtual TextIndexWord TextIndexWord { get; set; }
```

(highly recommended)

Then you can use the properties to get the desired results:

```
var results = 
    (
        from doc in db.Documents
        select new
        {
            doc,
            TotalOccurrences = 
                   doc.TextIndexDocuments
                      .Where(tid => lwords.Contains(tid.TextIndexWord.Word))
                      .Sum(doc => doc.Occurrences)
        }
    ).OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalOccurrences)
```

Comment: Thanks - this looks like it should do the job. However, I'm currently trying to fix tiw.Occurrences though, since that field is in the TextIndexDocuments table, not the TextIndexWord table.

Comment: Ah, .Sum(tiw => docTable.Occurences)

Comment: Hmm, not sure. You actually want sums per `Document`. The whole query must be lifted one level up.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this can not, or at least easily, be accomplished in LINQ, especially in any kind of performant way.

What you really should consider, assuming your DBA will allow it, is [Full-Text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) indexing of your documents stored in SQL Server. From my understanding the [RANK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) operator is exactly what you are looking for which has been highly optimized for Full-Text.

In response to your comment: (sorry for not noticing that)

You'll need to either do a series of subqueries or [Common-Table-Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx). CTE's are a bit hard to get used to writing at first but once you get used to them they are far more elegant than the corresponding query written with sub queries. Either way the query execution plan will be exactly the same, so there is no performance gain from going the CTE route.

Comment: Appreciated, though I think I end up with the same problem as the documents are actually references to several other unrelated tables (forum posts, articles, product pages, etc). In other words, I could do a full text search on forum posts, another on articles etc but still need to combine the results into one meaningful list ranked by number of hits.

Comment: I updated my answer with further hints, sorry I'm not spoon-feeding but I don't even have SSMS or SQL Server installed on my box right now

Answer (score 0):

You want to add up occurences for the words per document. So group by document ID, use `SUM` and order by total descending:

```
select documentid, sum(occurences)
from doctable
where wordid in (select id from wordtable where word in 'quick', 'brown', 'fox') 
group by documentid
order by sum(occurences) desc;
```